# Flutter ArgumentError (Invalid argument(s): Missing scheme in uri: Shein.com)

Tags: flutter, dart, webview, uri

I am using a `WebView` in my Flutter-App but it fails when trying to parse a URL like `shein.com`.

This is my setup:

```
Uri? uri = Uri.tryParse(widget.initUrl);
    if (uri == null) {
      AlertService.showSnackBar(
        title: 'Seite konnte nicht geöffnet werden.'.tr,
        description:
            'Vergewisser dich, dass es sich um eine korrekte URL handelt.'.tr,
        isSuccess: false,
      );
    } else {
      _controller.loadRequest(Uri.parse(
        widget.initUrl,
      ));
    }
  }
```

As you can see I am already using `tryParse` but apparently this doesn't check for a `scheme`. How can I check that? Or how can I load the request correctly?

Comment: `shein.com`  misses a scheme. It needs to be `https://shein.com` for example.

Comment: If you are sure it's never included with the `initUrl` then just do `Uri? uri = Uri.tryParse('https://' + widget.initUrl);`

Comment: @Ivo it can also be http://shein.com. So I guess I could simply check if it contains http and then build together a new String. But I thought tryParse would also handle this. I guess not :(